# How to get the values in items without refreshing the page in apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an item to enter email id, and two more items to get the values of first/last name and department of that user which we have given without refresh the page or without enter.

Item 1: ex : a...z@gmail.com (text field)
Item 2 : ex Mechanical (display only)
Item 3 : ex Abinnaya Moorthy (display only)

This should happen when we have given the email id and as soon as the cursor is out from email id the two item values should display.

I have used dynamic action but not getting exact output, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I have 1 field like an email field above. Then I have 50 display only fields that values are coming from (Source) SQL queries that depends on email field. How to refresh this fields without refreshing page, but also without Setting its value manually? I would only like to trigger them to perform their Source SQL query and refresh values on the page.

Setting their values by SetValue action will result in having same queries in Dynamic Action and in Source SQL Query for each field. Also for 50 fields DA would have hundreds of SQL lines and would become not maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

On Item 1 make a following dynamic action:

1. Event: **Change**  (I would recommend 'change', although based on your question, you might also be interested in 'Mouse Leave', although it would trigger DA even when no change in item value occurred, for example when someone just clicked on it and clicked away)
2. Selection Type: Item
3. Item: your Item 1
4. First true action: **Execute PL/SQL Code**

   5. inserting values into your items Item 2 and Item 3, while using your Item 1 as a condition in WHERE clause
   6. **Page Items to Submit: your Item 1**
   7. **Page Items to Return: your items Item 2 and Item 3**
5. Second true action: **Refresh**

   6. Selection Type: **Item(s)**
   7. Item(s): your items Item1 and Item2

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply, same i have tried but item 2 and 3 is not giving any vaulue

Comment: Hi, sorry it did mistake, its working fine...thanks :-)

Comment: @Abinnaya I'm glad it does. Can you please rate the answer and select it as correct if it helped you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are working on page 9, and the email field is :P9_EMAIL_ITEM, and the name fields are :P9_FNAME_ITEM and :P9_LNAME_ITEM

1. The email field is a text field (it doesn't matter what the source is)
2. The name fields should be display only, and in properties the setting "Based On" should be "Page Item Value", set the source property to type Null.
3. On the email text field, create a new dynamic action, set the When properties to: Event -> Change, Selection Type -> Item(s), Item(s) -> P9_EMAIL_ITEM
4. Under the dynamic actions you'll have a "New" event, with a "True" folder, and inside it a new action (probably "Show"). Change its action to "Set Value".
   change the setting property so that "Set Type" will be "SQL statement", and write a statement with the following structure:

   select FNAME_COLUMN,  LNAME_COLUMN

   from   RELEVANT_TABLE

   where  EMAIL_COLUMN = :P9_EMAIL_ITEM
5. Under "Items to submit" select the P9_EMAIL_ITEM. 
   in the Affected Elements properties set Selection type -> Item(s) and Item(s) -> P9_FNAME_ITEM, P9_LNAME_ITEM
6. In "Execution Options" select NO for Fire on Initialization

what we did on step 5 is "refreshing" the relevant items, without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it out and here's what works very well:

1. On Item 1, create a DA on 'Loose Focus'
2. Create two true actions for 'Set Value', for both Item 2 and Item 3.
3. Select Settings > Set Type as SQL Statement.
4. Write query to fetch item 2 and item 3, base on item 1 (I suggest comparing lower cases of both to make it case in-sensitive.)
5. Items to Submit -> Item 1

And viola, it's done!